# pdpbox won't install because of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, pip

I am trying to install pdpbox package on Python 3.9 on Windows using VSCode.
I don't understand the error, as I am already using matplotlib.
I can check that I have it installed when I use the command pip freeze. Any help to solve this error  would be appreciated please. I would like to use the package to see the dependance between features in a gradient boosting model using one hot encoding...

---

```
Collecting PDPbox
  Using cached PDPbox-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl
...
Collecting matplotlib==3.1.1
  Using cached matplotlib-3.1.1.tar.gz (37.8 MB)
... 
Building wheels for collected packages: matplotlib
  Building wheel for matplotlib (setup.py) ... /    
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mdelal001\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-od_rzv_2\\matplotlib_822e8f23ac7a46ca8f5401576ae554de\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mdelal001\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-od_rzv_2\\matplotlib_822e8f23ac7a46ca8f5401576ae554de\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-tlyp2uts'
       cwd: C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-od_rzv_2\matplotlib_822e8f23ac7a46ca8f5401576ae554de\
  Complete output (505 lines):    ================================================================================
  Edit setup.cfg to change the build options    
  BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
 ...
  creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DFREETYPE_BUILD_TYPE=system -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -Iextern/agg24-svn/include -Ic:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows K...      checkdep_freetype2.c
  src/checkdep_freetype2.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ft2build.h': No such file or directory
  error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for matplotlib
  Running setup.py clean for matplotlib
Failed to build matplotlib
Installing collected packages: matplotlib, PDPbox
  Attempting uninstall: matplotlib
    Found existing installation: matplotlib 3.4.2
    Uninstalling matplotlib-3.4.2:
      Successfully uninstalled matplotlib-3.4.2
    Running setup.py install for matplotlib ... /

ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mdelal001\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-od_rzv_2\\matplotlib_822e8f23ac7a46ca8f5401576ae554de\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mdelal001\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-od_rzv_2\\matplotlib_822e8f23ac7a46ca8f5401576ae554de\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2h2f7kk2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\matplotlib'
         cwd: C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-od_rzv_2\matplotlib_822e8f23ac7a46ca8f5401576ae554de\
    Complete output (505 lines):
    ================================================================================
    Edit setup.cfg to change the build options

    BUILDING MATPLOTLIB
```

...

```
    running install
    ...
    copying lib\matplotlib\mpl-data\images\home.svg -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\matplotlib\mpl-data\images
    copying lib\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\images\ui-icons_cc0000_256x240.png -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\matplotlib\backends\web_backend\jquery-ui-1.12.1\images
    UPDATING build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\matplotlib\_version.py
    ...
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -DFREETYPE_BUILD_TYPE=system -DPY_ARRAY_UNIQUE_SYMBOL=MPL_matplotlib_ft2font_ARRAY_API -DNPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API=NPY_1_7_API_VERSION -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS=1 -Iextern/agg24-svn/include -Ic:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\include -Ic:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -Ic:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29910\include -IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.8\include\um -IC:\Program Files ...
  /Tcsrc/checkdep_freetype2.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.9\Release\src/checkdep_freetype2.obj
        checkdep_freetype2.c
        src/checkdep_freetype2.c(1): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'ft2build.h': No such file or directory
        error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2019\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.28.29910\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit code 2
        ----------------------------------------
      Rolling back uninstall of matplotlib
      Moving to c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\__pycache__\pylab.cpython-39.pyc
       from C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-fnonqcom\pylab.cpython-39.pyc
      Moving to c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.4.2-py3.9-nspkg.pth
       from C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-yr2h9vlq\matplotlib-3.4.2-py3.9-nspkg.pth
      Moving to c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-3.4.2.dist-info\
       from C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~atplotlib-3.4.2.dist-info
      Moving to c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\
       from C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\~atplotlib
      Moving to c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid1\
       from C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\~xes_grid1
      Moving to c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\axes_grid\
       from C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\~xes_grid
      Moving to c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\axisartist\
       from C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\~xisartist
      Moving to c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\mplot3d\
       from C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\~plot3d
      Moving to c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\tests\
       from C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\mpl_toolkits\~ests
      Moving to c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages\pylab.py
       from C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-uninstall-yr2h9vlq\pylab.py
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\mdelal001\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-od_rzv_2\\matplotlib_822e8f23ac7a46ca8f5401576ae554de\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\mdelal001\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-od_rzv_2\\matplotlib_822e8f23ac7a46ca8f5401576ae554de\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --record 'C:\Users\mdelal001\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-2h2f7kk2\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'c:\users\mdelal001\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\Include\matplotlib' Check the logs for full command output.
```